# Unable to unmarshall XML to POJO using jackson in camel route

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jackson, apache-camel

I'm trying  to unmarshall XML to POJO VmML class to pass it throught our system. The POJO classes was created from dtd file using jaxb2 maven plugin. When I use feature camel-jaxb in karaf I was able to unmarshall XML file into object of class VmML without any problem, but for some reasons I have to pull back this approach, and finally I end up with camel-jacksonxml.

In the route now I'm using unmarshall tag as below.

```
    <dataFormats>
      <jacksonxml id="jack" unmarshalTypeName="com.company.generated.VmML"/>
    </dataFormats>

   <rest path="/service" 
      consumes="application/xml" 
      produces="text/plain">

    <post uri="/requestXmlCfg" 
      type="com.company.generated.VmML" 
      outType="java.lang.String">
      <route>
        <unmarshal ref="jack"/>
        <to uri="bean:messageProcessot?method=process"/>
      </route>
    </post>
    </rest>
```

I want to emphasize that it works earlier without unmarshaling tag, when I use simple camel-jaxb feature.

Now I get the exception which appears here often, but in my case the solutions are not proper because the data is provided and I don't want to skip anything. The error is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ReportType" (class com.company.generated.CarrierReport), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "CarrierReportSnapshot", "CarrierReportHeader", "CarrierReportPeriod"])
 at [Source: org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyChannelBufferStreamCache@612e834b; line: 6, column: 42] (through reference chain: com.company.generated.VmML["CarrierReport"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.company.generated.CarrierReport["ReportType"])
```

POJO classes was created bas on: http://www.vmml.org/spec/VmML_v0.1.dtd

And the XML is filled properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE VmML SYSTEM "http://www.vmml.org/spec/VmML_v0.1.dtd">
<VmML Version="0.1">
    <CarrierReport>
        <CarrierReportHeader>
            <ReportType SystemReference="aa">VMML</ReportType>
            <ReportTimestamp Timezone="0" TimeFormat="RFC822">Tue, 07 May 2013 15:21:14 %2B0000</ReportTimestamp>
            <SenderId SystemReference="aa">aa</SenderId>
            <ReceiverId SystemReference="aa">aa</ReceiverId>
            <SystemSource>aa</SystemSource>
            <SystemDestination>aa</SystemDestination>
        </CarrierReportHeader>
        <CarrierReportSnapshot>
            <Event>
                <EventHeader>
                    <EventTimestamp Timezone="0" TimeFormat="RFC822">Tue, 07 May 2013 15:21:14 %2B0000</EventTimestamp>
                    <EventCode SystemReference="aa">aa</EventCode>
                    <EventText>aa</EventText>
                </EventHeader>
            </Event>
        </CarrierReportSnapshot>
    </CarrierReport>
</VmML>
```

VMML class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "carrierReport"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "VmML")
public class VmML {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Version", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String version;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String id;
    @XmlElement(name = "CarrierReport", required = true)
    protected List<CarrierReport> carrierReport;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String value) {
        this.version = value;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    public List<CarrierReport> getCarrierReport() {
        if (carrierReport == null) {
            carrierReport = new ArrayList<CarrierReport>();
        }
        return this.carrierReport;
    }
}
```

CarrierReport class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "carrierReportHeader",
    "carrierReportSnapshot",
    "carrierReportPeriod"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CarrierReport")
public class CarrierReport {

    @XmlElement(name = "CarrierReportHeader", required = true)
    protected CarrierReportHeader carrierReportHeader;
    @XmlElement(name = "CarrierReportSnapshot")
    protected CarrierReportSnapshot carrierReportSnapshot;
    @XmlElement(name = "CarrierReportPeriod")
    protected CarrierReportPeriod carrierReportPeriod;

    public CarrierReportHeader getCarrierReportHeader() {
        return carrierReportHeader;
    }


    public void setCarrierReportHeader(CarrierReportHeader value) {
        this.carrierReportHeader = value;
    }


    public CarrierReportSnapshot getCarrierReportSnapshot() {
        return carrierReportSnapshot;
    }

    public void setCarrierReportSnapshot(CarrierReportSnapshot value) {
        this.carrierReportSnapshot = value;
    }

    public CarrierReportPeriod getCarrierReportPeriod() {
        return carrierReportPeriod;
    }

    public void setCarrierReportPeriod(CarrierReportPeriod value) {
        this.carrierReportPeriod = value;
    }

}
```

ReportType

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ReportType")
public class ReportType {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "SystemReference")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String systemReference;
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    public String getSystemReference() {
        return systemReference;
    }

    public void setSystemReference(String value) {
        this.systemReference = value;
    }

    public String getvalue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setvalue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Vmml > Carier Report > **Carier Report Header** > ReportType class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "reportType",
    "reportTimestamp",
    "senderId",
    "receiverId",
    "systemSource",
    "systemDestination",
    "missionId",
    "missionName"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CarrierReportHeader")
public class CarrierReportHeader {

    @XmlElement(name = "ReportType", required = true)
    protected ReportType reportType;
    @XmlElement(name = "ReportTimestamp", required = true)
    protected ReportTimestamp reportTimestamp;
    @XmlElement(name = "SenderId", required = true)
    protected SenderId senderId;
    @XmlElement(name = "ReceiverId")
    protected ReceiverId receiverId;
    @XmlElement(name = "SystemSource", required = true)
    protected String systemSource;
    @XmlElement(name = "SystemDestination")
    protected String systemDestination;
    @XmlElement(name = "MissionId")
    protected MissionId missionId;
    @XmlElement(name = "MissionName")
    protected String missionName;

    public ReportType getReportType() {
        return reportType;
    }

    public void setReportType(ReportType value) {
        this.reportType = value;
    }

    public ReportTimestamp getReportTimestamp() {
        return reportTimestamp;
    }

    public void setReportTimestamp(ReportTimestamp value) {
        this.reportTimestamp = value;
    }

    public SenderId getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public void setSenderId(SenderId value) {
        this.senderId = value;
    }

    public ReceiverId getReceiverId() {
        return receiverId;
    }

    public void setReceiverId(ReceiverId value) {
        this.receiverId = value;
    }

    public String getSystemSource() {
        return systemSource;
    }

    public void setSystemSource(String value) {
        this.systemSource = value;
    }

    public String getSystemDestination() {
        return systemDestination;
    }

    public void setSystemDestination(String value) {
        this.systemDestination = value;
    }

    public MissionId getMissionId() {
        return missionId;
    }

    public void setMissionId(MissionId value) {
        this.missionId = value;
    }

    public String getMissionName() {
        return missionName;
    }

    public void setMissionName(String value) {
        this.missionName = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your POJO class?

Comment: Hmm, I cannot see anywhere in yoru POJO where the class ReportType is referenced. Could be why it is reported is unrecognized?

Comment: Ok, I added the class and the refernece chain

Comment: The xml you receive is not valid - You have a `ReportType` in a `CarrierReport`which should not be possible. As you said you have this error "often", I assume the xml you show here is not the xml with issues.

Comment: @JérémieB - XML is valid
<CarrierReport>
        <CarrierReportHeader>
            <ReportType SystemReference="aa">VMML</ReportType>

Comment: jaxb doesn't create nodes randomly; and this error is clear : you have sometime a node ReportType under a CarrierReport. You should check if every message you receive is valid.

Comment: I never have ReportType under CarrierReport. I send the XML given as example above. Report typs is on the first place in Carier Report Header

Comment: I agree with Jeremie, the error seems to indicate that the field is coming in a place it shouldn't. Easiest would be to add log statements and print the body of the incoming xml message and compare a happy case with the one failing. Pretty sure data is at fault here.

Comment: This is how the body looks like already in camel route - this log was entered above unmarshall tag - http://scr.hu/0uc2/v1cip

Comment: And here you can find body cast to String which I feed the deserializer http://scr.hu/0uc2/f00ut